# Connecting air conditioner to Apple's HomeKit

Tags: raspberry-pi, arduino, apple-homekit

I'm planning to connect my air conditioner to Apple's HomeKit app. At first I searched for ways to do it, but I couldn't find a solution that would work for that project.

As I've found, Apple actually released a 'non commercial' protocol specification for creating your own HomeKit 'smart items' ([Link](https://developer.apple.com/support/homekit-accessory-protocol/)).

I also search for any kind of implementations of that protocol, but I only managed to find the simplest projects, e.g. [connecting a light bulb to HomeKit](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/make-diy-siri-controlled-wi-fi-light/).

The air conditioner that I'm planning to work on is an *LG P12EN.NSJ*. (I should probably include a data sheet of that device, but the only thing I managed to find was a useless manual, which doesn't really help). Probably the most important thing about it is that it doesn't have a Wi-Fi module built in, as some of those devices do. I guess it would make it a little easier to work with.

All in all, I'm here to ask one question: Is it possible to connect this device to HomeKit? As for now, I really don't even have a clue on how it should be done.

Comment: Are you planning to use an arduino or Pi for the connectivity? It's not in your question but in the tags.

Comment: After reading some articles on making HomeKit-enabled accessories, I think that using Arduino or Pi is actually a pretty good idea.

Comment: Page 27 of the useless manual briefly mentions an optional WiFi module which has a manual of its own.

Comment: Can someone update the missing "Link" in the second paragraph, or has it been completely removed?

Answer (score 1):

Start using home bridge. It is a simple way to connect unofficial accessories to HomeKit nearly flawlessly. See the guides on their main page: https://homebridge.io. You need a computer for the server. Most use a raspberry pi since it is cheap, easiest to use, & low power. However, it is possible to run it on an always-on computer.

Unfortunately, your AC is so old that no plugins seem to be made for it due to an obscure or nonexistent API. However, you can use an IR controller, such as the [broad link mini 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FK2SDOC). This can be connected to home bridge via a plugin. Broadlink is not the smoothest experience, since it is uni-directional (TO AC only), but it might work well enough for you.

Before you buy anything, you might want to install homebridge on your computer and just try different plugins. See if one works. If so, great! Get a pi and put the same home bridge plugin on there. If not, get a broad link from a place that accepts returns & try it. If you like it, get a pi & set up home bridge there. If you already have a pi, then you can start experimenting on there from the get-go - but I don't recommend spending money unless you've tried alternatives or done some testing.

NOTE: for remote control of HomeKit & automations, you will need an apple home hub. An iPad with a setting toggled, Apple TV 4th gen or later, or a HomePod (or home pod mini) all act as a hub.

Comment: As of iPadOS 16.2, I don’t think an iPad can be used as a home hub anymore. You have to use either an Apple TV or a HomePod.

Comment: @nsayer im still getting the option on my ipad pri 11 inch 2020 with ipados 16.2. Ill test it when i get back from vacation in 2 days.